# Headset and BB compatibility Kona Rove LTD 2019

Tags: bottom-bracket, headset, bearings, gravel

I've got a Kona Rove LTD 2019 and it's about time to change bearings.

This is the exact model : https://99spokes.com/en-EU/bikes/kona/2019/rove-ltd

I'd like to change headset and BB because they're creaking. And I'd like to go for more durable brands than the FSA or SRAM, like Hope or Chris King.

I'm rather new to all these standards and would like to make sure I order the right things.

Results of my investigation:

**Headset**

Norm: ZS 44/56

Compatible products:

- https://www.hopetech.com/products/controls/headsets/tapered-headset/
- https://chrisking.com/products/headset-inset-2

**BB**

Norm: BSA 68/73 + GXP 22-24 crank spindle

Compatible products:

- https://www.hopetech.com/products/drivetrain/bottom-bracket/bottom-bracket-threaded/ + https://www.hopetech.com/_repository/1/documents/29mm_BB_Conversion_Kit_001.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBobP1-Oz_AhXOU6QEHbB8A7QQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1ddRRHnyjopy1D0HatNDQq
- https://chrisking.com/collections/all-bottom-brackets/products/bottom-bracket-threadfit-24 + https://chrisking.com/products/threadfit-24-bottom-bracket-fit-kits?variant=31504343761014

Is this right? Is any adapter or stuff missing? Really unsure about BB...
If not, can you lead me to the right parts and explain what I got wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This SE avoids product recommendations, and I think you have worded this question to avoid that by limiting it to "would these be compatible." Well done.